# HW accelerated activity - how to get OpenGL texture size limit?

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, hardware-acceleration

I'm trying to enable hw acceleration in Honeycomb, and display some Bitmaps on Canvas.
All works fine, but for large bitmaps (>2048 in one dimension), I get error in log:

**OpenGLRenderer: Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture**

I know this is because of hw limitation, and can work-around it by reducing max bitmap size to be displayed if hw acceleration is enabled (checking by View.isHardwareAccelerated()).

My question is: how to easily determine max texture size available for Bitmap drawing by hardware.
2048 seems to be limit on my device, but it may be different on different ones.

Edit: I'm not creating OpenGL app, just normal app, which can utilize hw acceleration. Thus I'm not familiar with OpenGL at all, I just see OpenGL related error in log, and look to solve it.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Currently the minimum limit is 2048px (i.e. the hardware **must** support textures at least 2048x2048.) In ICS we will introduce a new API on the Canvas class that will give you this information:
`Canvas.getMaximumBitmapWidth()` and `Canvas.getMaximumBitmapHeight()`.

Comment: The method is called getMaximumBitmapHeight(). But it is not a static Method. Is there a static method or Constant that gives me values that I can use to download or resize Images without creating a Canvas Object for that every time?

Comment: There is not, but I could add one. Note that creating a Canvas will give you a different answer since you will be using a software Canvas.

Comment: It would be great to have a constant that contains the max texture size. Is 2048x2048 a reasonable default or are there devices with lower texture capabilities?

Comment: It cannot be a constant as it depends on the GPU. 2048x2048 is a perfectly reasonable assumption.

Comment: This cannot be true! I ran into a problem displaying an image of 1236x835 on a Galaxy Nexus!! My old HTC Hero is capable of displaying that! And: it's just a static image! I don't believe what I see there. How can I get around this??

Comment: On the G-N (Glaxy Nexus), a background of 720x1200 gives this error. I agree with @Zordid - Part of this answer is **NOT** true.

Comment: 2048x2048 is the maximum texture size on GN. You are most likely running into this problem because your image is in the wrong density bucket. GN is an xhdpi device, so if your 720x1200 image is in the drawable folder for instance, it will be scaled by 100% and end up being 1440x2400.

Comment: Very helpful indeed Romain, I was facing a similar issue and this image scaling explains a lot. Is there any documentation on how this scaling is done?

Comment: Is there a way to get the max texture size without using a Canvas Object? We are facing the following Problem: We are downloading images from the net that are shown in ViewPager. Since the images can be any size we try to limit them to the max texture size on the device itself. We don't have a proper Canvas at hand at the moment of saving the image.

Comment: The Nexus 10 supports up to 4096x4096 already. This method is nice, but as already mentioned, you have to be careful since you need a Hardware-Accelerated canvas to get the right value

Comment: I'm thinking of adding a static method somewhere for a future version.

Comment: @RomainGuy both of those methods just return a static value Canvas.MAXMIMUM_BITMAP_SIZE, which is equal to `32766`. That doesn't seem right...?

Comment: @TSGames is there an example of how to use the 2 methods? Doing (new Canvas()).getMaximumBitmap{Width,Height()} seems to return an incorrect 32766 on the GN5.

Comment: @HenriSweers On a Hardware accelerated canvas it returns the correct value.  So you'll have to use a real View with `setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null)` before getting the value.  The `32788` value is only for a software based canvas.

Comment: @Tspoon  What can I do without using it on an ImageView ? What are the steps exactly?

Comment: @HenriSweers
Android use opengl to draw instead of skia. So the canvas instance will be GLES20Canvas, take a look at it and you will get the key.

Comment: @Tspoon this is incorrect — `setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null)` does not influence "hardware" status of canvas if HW acceleration is already enabled in app. It simply renders the View in separate HW buffer (this is actually useless in case of ImageView, which already stores it's Bitmap in texture during display list creation).

Answer (score 18):

Another way of getting the maximum allowed size would be to loop through all EGL10 configurations and keep track of the largest size.

```
public static int getMaxTextureSize() {
    // Safe minimum default size
    final int IMAGE_MAX_BITMAP_DIMENSION = 2048;

    // Get EGL Display
    EGL10 egl = (EGL10) EGLContext.getEGL();
    EGLDisplay display = egl.eglGetDisplay(EGL10.EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY);

    // Initialise
    int[] version = new int[2];
    egl.eglInitialize(display, version);

    // Query total number of configurations
    int[] totalConfigurations = new int[1];
    egl.eglGetConfigs(display, null, 0, totalConfigurations);

    // Query actual list configurations
    EGLConfig[] configurationsList = new EGLConfig[totalConfigurations[0]];
    egl.eglGetConfigs(display, configurationsList, totalConfigurations[0], totalConfigurations);

    int[] textureSize = new int[1];
    int maximumTextureSize = 0;

    // Iterate through all the configurations to located the maximum texture size
    for (int i = 0; i < totalConfigurations[0]; i++) {
        // Only need to check for width since opengl textures are always squared
        egl.eglGetConfigAttrib(display, configurationsList[i], EGL10.EGL_MAX_PBUFFER_WIDTH, textureSize);

        // Keep track of the maximum texture size
        if (maximumTextureSize < textureSize[0])
            maximumTextureSize = textureSize[0];
    }

    // Release
    egl.eglTerminate(display);

    // Return largest texture size found, or default
    return Math.max(maximumTextureSize, IMAGE_MAX_BITMAP_DIMENSION);
}
```

From my testing, this is pretty reliable and doesn't require you to create an instance.
Performance-wise, this took 18 milliseconds to execute on my Note 2 and only 4 milliseconds on my G3.

Comment: This gives you the maximum **PBuffer** size. That's not the same as getting the maximum texture size. They may be the same values on some devices, but there's absolutely no guarantee for that.

Comment: On every device I tried this seems to work properly.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to know dynamically the texture size limit of your device (because it's change depending on the device), you have to call this method:

```
int[] maxTextureSize = new int[1];
gl.glGetIntegerv(GL10.GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE, maxTextureSize, 0);
```

And don't forget that for some device (the Nexus One for example), the texture size must be a power of 2 !

I know my answer comes a long time after the last update of this topic...sorry

Comment: Where is gl?  Is that a native android class, or do i need to import OpenGL into the project?  I know its on my device.

Comment: gl is the GL10 object that your GLSurfaceView.Renderer give you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works. One note: It's a static method, so you can simply call `GLES10.glGetIntegerv(...)`

Answer (score 4):

According to the specification, calling `glGetIntegerv` with `GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE`.

> GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE params returns one value. The value gives a rough estimate of the largest texture that the GL can handle. The value must be at least 64.

http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGet.xml

Comment: Tried this already in Activity.onCreate, but doesn't seem to work, returns 0. Probably it misses some GL initialization.

Comment: @mice: Exactly, the OpenGL context is not yet set at the point you call `glGetIntegerv`.

Comment: K-ballo: but I'm not creating OpenGL app, and don't care about some context. HW acceleration is hadled by system http://bit.ly/qw7BML. Just my Bitmap is not drawn, I'm looking for a clever fix.