# Universal Image Loader OOM while loading image from drawable folder?

Tags: android, caching, image-processing, out-of-memory, universal-image-loader

I have an application that needs to display full screen image, i get images from drawable folder and they are like 150-250 kb but it still crashes and gives OutOfMemory error. Not of course very first image, but i load different images everytime user launches application.

As i checked cache folder, i saw images that library cached are about 700-800 kb not as small as mine. So there is something about caching. How can i prevent that happening?

Here is my configuration:

```
DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
            .cacheOnDisc(true)
            .cacheInMemory(true)
            .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(300))
            .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
            .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
            .build();

ImageLoaderConfiguration configuration = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(this)
            .defaultDisplayImageOptions(options)
            .build();

ImageLoader.getInstance().init(configuration);
```

And second question: what is default cache limit? Or is there any? Should i specify myself? Because i do not desire to keep all images in cache, please assume that i will also use library to load images from internet not only from drawable.

**Edit:** I just find out [this page](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/wiki/Useful-Info) which explains a lot, but i see that by default library uses UnlimitedDiscCache and it provides faster caching... Now i have a dilemma about having faster cache (which is really important in my application) or having limited cache size and saving user from clearing cache folder manually... What should it be?

**Edit 2:** Here is OutOfMemory stackTrace:

```
E/dalvikvm-heap(17258): Out of memory on a 25600016-byte allocation.
I/dalvikvm(17258): "uil-pool-1-thread-2" prio=4 tid=14 RUNNABLE
I/dalvikvm(17258):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x428941b0 self=0x59672008
I/dalvikvm(17258):   | sysTid=17620 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps/bg_non_interactive handle=1572156040
I/dalvikvm(17258):   | schedstat=( 104225123 75715335 52 ) utm=10 stm=0 core=0
I/dalvikvm(17258):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
I/dalvikvm(17258):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:623)
I/dalvikvm(17258):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:476)
I/dalvikvm(17258):   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:781)
I/dalvikvm(17258):   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1963)
I/dalvikvm(17258):   at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:672)
I/dalvikvm(17258):   at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromDrawable(BaseImageDownloader.java:188)
I/dalvikvm(17258):   at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader.getStream(BaseImageDownloader.java:85)
I/dalvikvm(17258):   at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.downloadImage(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:319)
I/dalvikvm(17258):   at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryCacheImageOnDisc(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:298)
I/dalvikvm(17258):   at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryLoadBitmap(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:241)
I/dalvikvm(17258):   at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.run(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:141)
I/dalvikvm(17258):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
I/dalvikvm(17258):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
I/dalvikvm(17258):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
A/libc(17258): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 17620 (uil-pool-1-thre)
```

**Edit 3:**

Problem solved, please see my own answer. But i accepted Delblanco's answer, because it is more efficient.

Comment: **Size on disc != size in memory**, a bitmap with default configuration takes w*h*4 bytes in memory, for a 2 mpixel image that means 8 Mb memory

Comment: Could you post the OOM exception stack trace?

Comment: By 'As i checked cache folder' i meant size on disc... @Magnus

Comment: Updated question with stackTrace @Magnus

Comment: Which folder do you mean by 'i get images from drawable folder'. is it some download folder of yours, or the 'R.drawable.***'

Comment: R.drawable folder @Delblanco

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If possible you should use the native way of showing images from drawable folder. [Source](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader#acceptable-uris-examples)

Comment: Yeah, but i thought that way i should've handled scaling issues by myself and i was already using this library so decided to go with it. But i didn't know that it is especially declared in library's page to use native way. So i'll give it a shot. Thanks ;)

Comment: And that's even better solution than using Universal Image Loader, so i'll accept your answer. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

25600016 bytes, is a 25 Mb you're asking to load into memory, or equivalent of a 6 mpixel image with `ARGB_8888` `Bitmap.Config`. It's way to big to load, you need to downsample (see [inSampleSize](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html#load-bitmap)) and read [this](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html). In your case you should **UIL** to downscale the image. I see also that you explicitly set the `Bitmap.Config` to `RGB_565` which means that you actually are dealing with an even larger image, 12 mpixel image?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the issue. The problem was i had put images into `drawable` folder before. Images are really big, like 1000*1600px, so i move them into `drawable-xxhdpi` folder and somehow OutOfMemory error disappears. Any idea why?

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14877627/2246121 the system tried to scale up your "small" images to become huge on those systems with higher pixel density.

Comment: See the [Providing Resources documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources). Normally I supply for all device screen resolutions I want to support, with the most common being the mdpi/hdpi/xhdpi/xxhdpi folders.