# Bitmap not displaying on canvas

Tags: android, view, bitmap, android-canvas, android-bitmap

Hi apologies for such a basic question. I've been trying to decode my image resource into a bitmap and draw it onto my canvas within my customView.

I've compared this issue to several similar Stackoverflow questions and have tried other methods but have had no luck displaying the image.

```
public class CircleView extends View implements View.OnTouchListener{


private Paint baseCircle, touchCircle;
private int xInput, yInput;
private int width, height;
private float circleCenterX, circleCenterY, circleRadius;
private Resources res;
private Bitmap bitmap;


public CircleView(Context context){
    super(context);

    res = getResources();
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.wheel);

    width = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
    height = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
    circleCenterX = width/2;
    circleCenterY = height/2;
    circleRadius = 500;

    baseCircle = new Paint();
    baseCircle.setColor(Color.GRAY);

    touchCircle = new Paint();
    touchCircle.setAntiAlias(true);
    touchCircle.setColor(Color.RED);

    setFocusable(true);
    this.setOnTouchListener(this);

}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    canvas.drawCircle(circleCenterX, circleCenterY, circleRadius,baseCircle);
    canvas.drawCircle(xInput, yInput, 50, touchCircle);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
}
```

Comment: did the drawCircle method of canvas work?

Comment: Yes! The issue only occurs with the bitmap.

Comment: Maybe could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21082184/canvas-drawbitmap-is-not-drawing-anything

Comment: Hi Valentino, I've tried the suggested methods in the link and have had no luck. I was able to getPixels and getHeight/getWidth of the bitmap, verifying that its not null.

Comment: Have you tried using a different bitmap?

Comment: I've tried a different bitmap now and I am able to view the image! I'm unsure as to why the other image is not working