# increase Bitmap size in android

Tags: android, bitmap, horizontal-scrolling, horizontalscrollview

I'm working on application that want show a long-width image as below to the user.
user can drag image to the right or left, to see entire image or use Gyro-Sensor instead.
[image: this is what i want]

so, i used HorizontalScrollView in android with layout code below to achive want i want

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="net.appersian.android.wod.MainActivity"
android:background="#000"
 >

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:measureAllChildren="false"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
    android:scrollbars="none" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/panorama_ph" />
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

this code works great on High-end device like Nexus 5 but the problem is started when i test the app on Nexus S(512MB ram) on android 4.2! image is not shown and in logcat, i get continusly this error:

```
09-09 13:58:27.539: W/OpenGLRenderer(7925): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (6759x1136, max=2048x2048)
```

i don't know either how to implement this effect without Horizontalscrollview or how to fix the problem!
can anyone help me to fix this problem?

Comment: to fixing your problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10271020/bitmap-too-large-to-be-uploaded-into-a-texture

Comment: thank you, but is there any other way to achieve this effect without horizontalscrollview?

Comment: i'm not sure about that but might be achievable with a one page ViewPager with setting page margins, but it's just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

you can try use photoView

```
        <uk.co.senab.photoview.PhotoView
            android:id="@+id/photo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone" />
```

MainActivity.class

```
import uk.co.senab.photoview.PhotoView;
import uk.co.senab.photoview.PhotoViewAttacher;

 public class MainActivity extends Fragment{
        PhotoViewAttacher mPhotoAttacher;
        PhotoView mPhoto;

        mPhoto = (PhotoView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.photo);


                public void imageView(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage)
                    {

                    mPhoto.setImageBitmap(loadedImage);
                    mPhoto.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mPhotoAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(mPhoto);
                }
        }
```

Comment: how can i fix zoom state?

Comment: i can't explain you more than you can try with  <uk.co.senab.photoview.PhotoView  /> for show large image bitmap