# Scaling images to different drawable folders taken from my phone to be used as header image

Tags: android

```
Android Studio 1.3
```

Hello,

I have taken some pictures from my Nexus 5 phone. I would like to use one for as a header that is loaded into a imageview.

However, I am not sure about the scaling and which drawable-xhdi, drawable-xxhdi etc, it should go in.

The picture I have currently is:

```
Width: 3200 pixels
Height: 2368 pixels
Size: 2.4 MB
file type: jpg
```

I have gimp photo edit tool that I can compress into a png file to reduce the size. But I am not sure how can I make the picture look good on other screen densities. Which drawable folder would I have to put each one in?

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: Scale a Drawable or background image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400782/android-scale-a-drawable-or-background-image)

Comment: i would just like to know you want to make it look good in only mobile phones between 4" -6"inches or you are targetting to tablets or not??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**1st** of all, you should know there is a [limit on image size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10271020/bitmap-too-large-to-be-uploaded-into-a-texture) :

> OpenGl maximum size is 2048x2048 or else it throws an error: Bitmap too large to be uploaded into texture.

**2nd** you must consider, what are devices you are targetting for. 
There are different [qualifiers](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#overview) in android:

> **Screen size**: 
>   Actual physical size, measured as the screen's diagonal.
>   For simplicity, Android groups all actual screen sizes into four generalized sizes: small, normal, large, and extra-large.
>
> **Screen density**
>   The quantity of pixels within a physical area of the screen; usually referred to as dpi (dots per inch). For example, a "low" density screen has fewer pixels within a given physical area, compared to a "normal" or "high" density screen.
>   For simplicity, Android groups all actual screen densities into six generalized densities: low, medium, high, extra-high, extra-extra-high, and extra-extra-extra-high.

- *small* and *normal size* - Handsets
- *large* size - 7' tablets (e.g. sw600 - smallest width 600dp)
- *xlarge* size - 10' tablets (e.g. sw720 - smallest width 720dp)

**3rd** look at [Android Dashboard](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html#Screens).

[image: Dashboard 03.09.2015]

Quick look reveals, that are *few ldpi* and *almost none xxxhdpi* devices. What does it mean? You don't need to provide resource for those folder. But do as you like.

> Note: You do not need to provide xxxhdpi assets for all your app's images.

**4th** Look at your application and find out the maximum size:

So if your image is going to be a header, I assume it will match_parent -> Let's say, you are designing your app to work on screen resolutions 1920*1080 (h*w) and lower. Now you see first important step. **If your image matches_parent and parent is maximum 1080px wide, you don't need 3200 px wide image!**

**5th** Resize the image using some tool like [9-Patch-Resizer](https://github.com/redwarp/9-Patch-Resizer) or [Android Asset Studio](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/) and add it to your drawable folders

**6th** Test it on devices and check if the image quality is good enough. On tablets, you might consider to use drawable-large and drawable-xlarge folder.

> - 320dp: a typical phone screen (240x320 ldpi, 320x480 mdpi, 480x800 hdpi, etc).
> - 480dp: a tweener tablet like the Streak (480x800 mdpi).
> - 600dp: a 7” tablet (600x1024 mdpi).
> - 720dp: a 10” tablet (720x1280 mdpi, 800x1280 mdpi, etc).

Answer (score 3):

first you should make a decision about how big the picture size you want in **dp** dimension.because dp is a device independent dimension.

for example, if you want you image to be `200 * 100` dp.
then 
the picture you put in the different drawable folder should be the size below:

```
drawable-ldpi    150 * 75    px 
drawable-mdpi    200 * 100   px
drawable-hdpi    300 * 150   px
drawable-xhdpi   400 * 200   px
drawable-xxhpi   600 * 300   px


3 : 4 : 6 : 8 : 12
mdpi means 1 dp = 1px
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the documentation here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#range

Quote:

> A set of six generalized densities:
>
> - ldpi (low) ~120dpi
> - mdpi (medium) ~160dpi
> - hdpi (high) ~240dpi
> - xhdpi (extra-high) ~320dpi
> - xxhdpi (extra-extra-high) ~480dpi
> - xxxhdpi (extra-extra-extra-high) ~640dpi

Answer (score 2):

If it is nexus5 it resolution is 1080 x 1920 pixels (~445 ppi pixel density)

As per set of generalized density as per android developer console

```
xhdpi (extra-high) ~320dpi

xxhdpi (extra-extra-high) ~480dpi
```

so nexus 5 will take drawable-xxhdpi for images