# How prevent Outofmemory Error loading big image?

Tags: android, out-of-memory, picasso

I have a Scrollview that contains 4 big size images 750x1023, 750x2265, 750x1898, and 750x1112

I load image with Picasso

```
Picasso.with(getContext()).load(resIds[i]).fit().centerCrop().into(mainImageview.get(i));
```

But it brings to OutOfMemory error.
It makes to problem:

1. not all images load
2. app closing

Its important not to make image smaller - it can make UI uncorrect.

What the way to solve this problem? id need, to post code of program - just say what piece.

Thanks!

After all manipulation, problem is still unsolved.. If i scale images with BitmapFactory, it gives "Bitmap too large to bu uploaded into a texture", what ever size i write. If a scale with picasso, it crops my image What ever i do, app memmory enought for two, three switching pages... I'm exhausted because of this problem ...Help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strange out of memory issue while loading an image to a Bitmap object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object)

Comment: Are you loading the images from the XML even before Picasso loads them?

Comment: @cricket_007 at first yes, but after deleting them from XML. Nothing changes

Comment: @nochindeluxe I read this topic. But still have not any idea, how it cab solve my problem..

Answer (score 0):

The issue I believe is with gl max size which is something like 2048x2048 and the error will be cannot apply texture or something to that effect Picasso has a lot of ways to scale images but if you must use the full size image then its possible to cut the image into 4 or more pieces and assemble it like Google maps check this ["Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10271020/bitmap-too-large-to-be-uploaded-into-a-texture)

Comment: Thanks, I ll try this way!

Comment: After all manipulation, problem is still unsolved.. If i scale images with BitmapFactory, it gives "Bitmap too large to bu uploaded into a texture", what ever size i write. If a scale with picasso, it crops my image
What ever i do, app memmory enought for two, three switching pages... I'm exhausted because of this problem ...Help