# Can Fresco's automatic resizing on big images (>2048px) be disabled/tuned?

Tags: android, image, fresco

On images with a >2048px long dimension Fresco [automatically applies a resizing](https://frescolib.org/docs/troubleshooting.html):

> Android cannot display images more than 2048 pixels long in either dimension. This is beyond the capability of the OpenGL rendering system. Fresco will resize your image if it exceeds this limit.

I understand that this is done as a workaround for the [OpenGL Android limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10271020/bitmap-too-large-to-be-uploaded-into-a-texture), but is there any way to control it?

Here is an example of how Fresco is rendering a 750x2440 image with the default settings:
[image]

And here is the same image on Picasso with the default settings:
[image]

I already tried playing with the Fresco's resizing/downsampling without success.

[Gist of the code used in the images above](https://gist.github.com/mmazzarolo/9fe9a142fe6259400c6fe3b19108f5e3)

P.S.: [Here's the URL of the image used in my testing](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1ZaMs3E-_TubRoiAg1BjQdD7ylpgVf_iH)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm able to achieve this using only [isResizeAndRotateEnabledForNetwork()](https://frescolib.org/javadoc/reference/com/facebook/imagepipeline/core/ImagePipelineConfig.html#isResizeAndRotateEnabledForNetwork()) from the [ImagePipelineConfig](https://frescolib.org/javadoc/reference/com/facebook/imagepipeline/core/ImagePipelineConfig.html) class, I didn't need to tweak downsampling.

It required adding an additional step when initializing Fresco (In Application class); by [configuring](https://frescolib.org/docs/configure-image-pipeline.html) an image pipeline.

This is what MyApplication class looks like:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        ImagePipelineConfig pipelineConfig = ImagePipelineConfig.newBuilder(this)
                .setResizeAndRotateEnabledForNetwork(false)
                .build();
        Fresco.initialize(this, pipelineConfig);
    }
}
```

So, instead of initializing Fresco with `Fresco.initialize(this)`, add an ImagePipeline class, configure it to disable resizing for images from the network using `.setResizeAndRotateEnabledForNetwork(false)`, then pass the configured pipeline class to Fresco.

When it's set to false:

[image: resize_is_false]

And then when it's set to true (most likely the default value):

[image: resize_is_true]

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I'm planning to test it soon and get back to mark it as solved.

Comment: Did `setResizeAndRotateEnabledForNetwork(false)` do the trick for you?

Comment: Just tested, it did. Thank you!

Comment: @Gnzlt It makes sense for the default to be true. I hadn't dived into the source code to confirm that it defaults to true. I inferred from his image (the blurry one) and then re-inferred (if that's a word) from my own solution by changing it to false and then the image comes out un-blurred.

Comment: You are right, I understood it the other way around