# Poor Map Overlay image quality on Android using react-native-maps

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

When overlaying large image over map, the quality of the image is degraded to a significant degree on Android devices. No issues with iOS. There's many articles regarding Fresco downsampling image issues and a possible fix could be [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53769797/can-frescos-automatic-resizing-on-big-images-2048px-be-disabled-tuned). If there was a way to expose the Fresco config when creating the [image request](https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/maps/ImageReader.java#L87), that could potentially solve the issue. Any guidance here?