# Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture after scaling it down

Tags: android, bitmap, android-imageview

I've made an application which has a big background. It runs perfectly on a Nexus 7, but on my Galaxy Nexus the background is gone and gives in the logcat the error: Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (...).

I've read [this](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) and also used the code which was on there. The code I used to set my background is this:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    width = display.getWidth();
    height = display.getHeight();


    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    ImageView achtergrond = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.achtergrond);
    achtergrond.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), R.drawable.achtergrond, width, height));
} (...)

public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}

public static int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
// Raw height and width of image
final int height = options.outHeight;
final int width = options.outWidth;
int inSampleSize = 1;

if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

    // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and width
    final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
    final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);

    // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will guarantee
    // a final image with both dimensions larger than or equal to the
    // requested height and width.
    inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
}

return inSampleSize;
```

}

The resolution of my R.drawable.achtergrond is: 1100x539. Also if I comment out that rule (setBitmapImage) then the errors stop. The whole time the background isn't showing up on my Galaxy Nexus while it does show up on my Nexus 7. The image is that big to be at a good resolution. The background image is at the moment in the drawable folder.

Thanks for helping me in advance!

Answer (score 11):

Move the background to the `drawable-nodpi` folder.

As it's been already said in [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14877627) to [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7428996) of yours, each device has a limitation on the maximum dimensions an image may have to be rendered as a texture on screen; this is typically 2048 for both width and height. However, if you put your drawable inside a folder without a density qualifier, Android assumes that drawable is mdpi and scale it up or down for other densities. If your screen has xhdpi density, for example, the drawable gets scaled up two times: 1100 x 2 = 2200, which is too large for the 2048 limit.