# Android Live Wallpaper with canvas.drawBitmap is way to slow

Tags: android, performance, android-canvas, live-wallpaper, drawbitmap

I just started android programming this week and am curently working on a Live Wallpaper.

I have 2 Images, the Background Image (720x1280 png) and a slidebar (2276x290 png) that slides from right to left in an endles loop. my Problem is I only get it to slide with about 3-4fps with 1 px per Frame (on my actual phone, on AVD I get about 1/3fps ), wich is way to choppy for a live wallpaper. The code is working fine so far but way to slow.

It would be very nice if someone would know a way to get this "a lot" faster.

My code:

```
private class WEngine extends Engine {
    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
    private final Runnable drawRunner = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            draw();
        }

    };
    private Paint paint = new Paint();
    private int width;
    int height;
    private boolean visible = true;
    int x = -1;
    int x2 = 0;
    int y = -1;

    public WEngine() {
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(WService.this);
        handler.post(drawRunner);

    }

    @Override
    public void onVisibilityChanged(boolean visible) {
        this.visible = visible;
        if (visible) {
            handler.post(drawRunner);
        } else {
            handler.removeCallbacks(drawRunner);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        super.onSurfaceDestroyed(holder);
        this.visible = false;
        handler.removeCallbacks(drawRunner);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format,
            int width, int height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        super.onSurfaceChanged(holder, format, width, height);
    }

    private void draw() {
        SurfaceHolder holder = getSurfaceHolder();
        Canvas canvas = null;
        Resources res = getResources();
        Bitmap backgroundimg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.background);
        Bitmap slidebarimg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.slidebar);

        try {
            canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
            canvas.drawBitmap(backgroundimg, 0, 0, paint);
            if (canvas != null) {
                if (x<0 && y<0) {
                     x = 0;
                     y = Math.round(height / 2);
                 } else {
                     x -= 1;
                 }

                if (x - width < -height * 1.778125) {
                    x2 -= 1; 
                }

                if (x < -height * 1.778125) {
                    x = x2;
                    x2 = 0;
                }

                canvas.drawBitmap(slidebarimg, x, y, paint);

                if (x2 < 0) {
                    canvas.drawBitmap(slidebarimg, x2, y, paint);
                }
            }
        } finally {
            if (canvas != null)
                holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);

        }

        handler.removeCallbacks(drawRunner);
        handler.postDelayed(drawRunner, 30);
    }
}
```

Edit:

After changing the Images to jpg files I get about 6 fps, but thats still way to slow.

Edit 2:

I just figured out that hardwareaccceleration is not possible while using .lockCanvas()
Is there another way to draw an image on livewallpaper (surfaceview) that provides hardwareaccceleration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void draw() {
    ...
    Bitmap backgroundimg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.background);
    Bitmap slidebarimg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.slidebar);
    ...
```

Don't do this. If you're decoding bitmaps in every frame, it's going to be slow. Very slow. It doesn't matter if you're hardware accelerated or not. Decode them once, and just *draw* them on each frame.

Answer (score 0):

There is OpenGl hardware texture size limit. In new devices it's mostly 2048px. Try keeping it your maximum.
( [HW accelerated activity - how to get OpenGL texture size limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7428996/hw-accelerated-activity-how-to-get-opengl-texture-size-limit) ) 
Also make sure that hardware acceleration is on in your app
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html

Comment: I just made sure hardware acceleration is on, but it's not used on my canvas (I added if (canvas.isHardwareAccelerated()) before drawing the slidebar Bitmap and it's not drawing it) I also reduced img sizes to 576x1024 and 320x290 to make sure, but it didn't had any effect. (except for the smaler images ofc)