# My Canvas Drawing is not shown in some devices ... strange behavior

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas

I have an application, I have created a custom view and implement onDraw Myself, The application take some bitmaps and draw them as list with some algorithm

I have used 9 item to test it and it works perfect, when I increase the number of items to 18 item and try to test, it draw item when I use portrait mode but draw nothing on landscape mode

It works on the following devices :

Samsung (GT-I5510) with 2.2 OS

Samsung (GT-S6500D) with 2.3.6 OS

HTC (Nexus One) with 2.3.6 OS

Sony (Xperia-ST23i) with 4.0.4 OS

TouchMate Tablet

it have a strange behavior in the following devices:

Samsung (Tablet GT-P3100, S2, S4) it show the drawing on portrait mode but it doesn't show it in landscape mode

HTC (OneX) it doesn't show drawing in portrait or landscape

I have the following warning show in Logcat

Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (Tablet)
Reached here in cacheGlyph

Can any one help please ? I think it may be something related to hardware

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try turning off the hardware acceleration.
This will explain everything you need to know about hardware acceleration: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html

Comment: it works after I turn off hardware acceleration in all devices except HTC (OneX) it doesn't show drawing in portrait or landscape, can you help me as I don't know what is the problem of this device

Comment: Do you get the same 'Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture' log? Also, it would be nice if you post your code.

Comment: yes I'm geeting this error : Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (696x2262, max=2048x2048)

Comment: I have found some posts about this problem in the following links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7428996/hw-accelerated-activity-how-to-get-opengl-texture-size-limit , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15313807/android-maximum-allowed-width-height-of-bitmap, I have tries to force openGL to maximize the limitation of Bitmap but it doesn't work in my device, so do you think I have to work in low level of openGL, or just try to get max bitmap size and then resize it

Comment: You can break the large bitmap into smaller pieces and load them into individual bitmaps. That way you wan't exceed the size limit.