# Check whether bitmap is shown when using setImageBitmap method

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, android-imageview, android-bitmap

I'm setting a bitmap in an imageview and, I've seen that the bitmap is not being always shown. Depending on the device this is not shown ought to a size problem, so I'm using bitmap options to scale it and then it is always shown.
However, I would like to scale the bitmap just when this is required but I don't know how to do that as the setImageBitmap's method is not throwing any exception and event getBitmap and getDrawable methods are returning a valid value instead of null even when the bitmap is not being shown.
How could I do that?

Thanks a lot

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7428996/hw-accelerated-activity-how-to-get-opengl-texture-size-limit

Comment: Thanks but then, do I have to create my own ImageView in order to check Canvas?

Comment: The accepted answer is actually *not* correct (AFAIK, that method currently returns hardcoded value). See other answers by Pkmmte and VinceFR, that contains working methods to learn that information from OpenGL.